# Ubuntu 21.04, Virtualenv and its configuration of Python

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, pip, virtualenv

**EDIT:**

- In addition to the behaviour outlined below, the Python3.10 based environment seems to be ignoring packages installed with the `pip -e` option (**development mode**).
- Specifically, a package installed in development mode is not listed in `pip freeze` (which, it does in the Python3.9 based virtual environment) and a simple `import <package_name>` fails. If the package is installed normally (i.e. **not** in development mode) everything works as expected.

---

I am using `virtualenv` to create a virtual environment based around Python 3.10. While `virtualenv` finishes without errors and does seem to activate, it still fails to pick up its own Python **unless** the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable has been set manually.

I am not sure if the situation I am faced with is due to Ubuntu's way of incorporating Python or the way virtualenv is setting up the environment so that it picks up a local interpreter. Here is what I have gathered this far:

1. My base system is an Ubuntu 21.04. It has its own Python 3 (Python3.9.5) installation which I have not touched at all except installing the `python3-virtualenv` package using `apt`.
2. With Python 3.10, I installed the `python3.10-dev` package and proceeded to create a virtual environment in the usual way:

   1. `> virtualenv -p python3.10 the_env/`
   2. `> source the_env/bin/activate`
3. Although this looks OK so far, this environment does not have **any** information about its own `site-packages` directory. Not even the one that `virtualenv` is supposed to be creating which includes `pip`. In this installation, if you try to `> pip --version` you simply get an error that
   the `pip` package does not exist (the `pip` "executable" location is picked up correctly, but because the interpreter does not know anything about its `site-packages` it fails to start pip properly).

Long story short, I created two environments, one based on Python3.9 (which works perfectly) and one based on Python3.10 (which does not work) and did a very simple test in **each** environment:

- `> python -m site`

  - On the Python3.9 environment, `sys.path` **includes** a path that leads all the way to this particular environment's `site-packages`
  - On the Python3.10 environment, `sys.path` **does not** include that particular path but still includes the typical paths you expect to find (e.g. those pointing to the interpreter itself and the top environment directory but **not** the specific path that points to the `site-packages` location.

Following this, I defined a `PYTHONPATH` *manually*, before activating the environment which points exactly to the `site-packages` for that particular environment and everything worked as expected.

I *suspect* that this might be something to do with the fact that my system's Python is 3.9 which means that the `USER_SITE` variable **is** valid while in the case of Python3.10, it is not (because, I do not have a use for it, this is just a virtual environment I am creating). So, I *suspect* that this might be throwing off the way the [`site` module determines where things are](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html).

As I am not sure, I would like to ask the following:

1. Could this be something to do with the way Ubuntu handles the Python installation that might just be creating this small problem with virtual environments?
2. Could the problem be with `virtualenv` that does not explicitly specify a `PYTHONPATH`?
3. Could this behaviour be something of a corner case of the `site` module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me is an installation from source. After unpacking the source code, as a summary:

```
$ ./configure --enable-optimizations --with-ensurepip=install --prefix=/path/to/install/to/
$ make -j
$ make test
$ make install
$ /path/to/install/to/bin/python3.10 -m venv /path/to/test
$ source /path/to/test/bin/activate
$ pip list
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        21.2.4
setuptools 58.1.0
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.4; however, version 21.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/path/to/test/bin/python3.10 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
$ python -m pip install --upgrade pip
[...]
$ pip list
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        21.3.1
setuptools 58.1.0
```

### Edit

As mentioned below, I believe the reason why the procedure above just works is simply that when building and installing Python from source, the installation simply will be correct, which I suspect the 3.10 installation in Ubuntu 21.04 is not.

I made my Python installation from source somewhere under my home directory, in order to not risk messing things up, and I also did not permanently modify the PATH.

Setting the path to `$PATH:/path/to/install/to/bin` should be fine however, either permanently, or just when running `mkvirtualenv`.

Doing that, my new installation even seems to integrate seamlessly with my system's `virtualenvwrapper`.

I don't really need to be on the Python leading edge myself, but if I did, I would definitely make myself independent of Ubuntu's latest development by using the procedure described above.

By the way, if I update `pip` directly in the Python installation built from source, I will no longer get the message about the older `pip` (see above) when I install new virtual environments.

### Edit 2

Bug reported to Ubuntu:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python3.10/+bug/1955742

### Edit 3

Also, since Ubuntu 21.04 has end of life in a month or so, upgrading to 21.10 could really make sense. I have just tried that, and it seems that Python 3.10 virtual environments work just fine in that release.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. Could you please elaborate on your answer? I do not understand how "installation from source" (for Python) would help in being able to create virtual environments using a python version other than the one installed on the system (?).

Comment: @A_A, as you can see in my answer, I do that by using the `venv` library as a script, from the newly installed Python, built from source. It just works, I guess simply because it is correctly installed, unlike Python 3.10 on Ubuntu 21.04 (still guessing). I usually use `virtualenvwrapper`, and the solution above does not seamlessly integrate with my existing instance of it. Since that is a Python module too, I guess I could fix that by installing it in the Python environment built from source. I don't in fact strictly need Python 3.10, so I will wait for an official Ubuntu solution, instead.

Comment: See my edit above, which is more updated than my previous comment. So basically, build Python from source, carefully update your `PATH`, and it will just work. Reporting a bug to Ubuntu could be an idea too.

Comment: I have now also reported the bug to Ubuntu (see Edit 2).

Comment: See Edit 3, too.

Comment: Hi, thank you for all of your effort, I appreciate it. I do not think that just upgrading solves the problem but certainly starting from a completely minimal ubuntu server 21.10 image does work.

Answer (score 0):

With the advent of Ubuntu 22.04 (which caused a few minor issues with some specific python virtualenv setups I had) and having already spent some time figureing this out, I ended up switching to using [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv).

Pyenv made it very easy to install any python version and any number of virtual environments within it which can be further customised in complete isolation.

The only thing to be careful of is installing all necessary python prerequisites before installing a specific version to avoid missing functionality from some packages (e.g. not including the `lzma` library will generate an ominous warning from pandas ("your python installation is incomplete..."). This can be ignored if you are not using that functionality or otherwise, easily fixed.

I think that this is a better option overall if you have to manage different versions and specific configurations for python, even across distros.

This solution is very close to the one suggested before ("install from source") so I will be accepting that one and leave my contribution as additional information about this problem.